# Implement stack using queue - the best complexity

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue, time-complexity

I am wondering if there is a way to implement a stack using as many queues as needed that pushes and pops data in O(1).
If there is not any O(1) algorithm , what is the best complexity then?

Comment: What do you mean by O(1)?

Comment: I mean the time taken by the algorithm should not be dependent to n-the size of the stack. It has to be constant

Comment: The time taken for algorithm to do what?

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you want to? Intuitively, I'm inclined to say O(n) would be best case.

Comment: @RobJinman any proof or something satisfying?

Comment: Well if you can implement a O(1) stack using an array, you could just as well use an array of 1-element queues, but that would be pointless. Could you define the problem better? Are you permitted to use arrays or variables, or must the solution consist entirely of queues?

Comment: I am asked to implement a stack using ONLY queues with the best complexity! Using queues in a way you mentioned does not support dynamic size and uses arrays-as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If recursively defined queues in queues are allowed then O(1) pushes/pops is possible using the following:

Code:

```
STACK:
  QUEUE q

PUSH (S, x):
  QUEUE temp
  ENQUEUE(temp, x)
  ENQUEUE(temp, S.q)
  S.q = temp


POP (S):
  ANY x := DEQUEUE(S.q) # Error here if queue is empty
  QUEUE S.q := DEQUEUE(S.q)
  return x
```

The result is a recursively formed stack.

If `[1,2]` represents a stack where `dequeue([1,2])` would return `1`. Then the data structure if `1` then `3` then `6` were pushed onto the stack would look like this:

```
[6,[3,[1,[]]]]
```

Comment: First I thought it's O(1), but then noticed that copying S.q when enqueuing it is still O(n).

Comment: Pass by reference not value there's no need to actually copy it. Modify the code as needed to ensure that the queues are not actually copied. My bad if the code implies that they are.

Comment: Then S.q will contain only x and a reference. And the reference points to nothing more because it points to itself.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps assign a pointer to the queue then enqueue the pointer instead of the queue. Maybe I shouldn't have copied Rob's pseudocode (or at least I treated it as pseudocode). Not sure offhand how it can be made to work in the language you are using but I know for a fact that it should be possible to make it work somehow. The code above would work in Python for example without modification.

Comment: Oh yes... I was misunderstood! Excellent algorithm. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stack with linear-time PUSH and constant-time POP.

Given a queue with functions ENQUEUE and DEQUEUE:

```
STACK:
  QUEUE q


PUSH (S, x):
  r := new QUEUE
  ENQUEUE(r, x)

  while S.q not empty:
    v := DEQUEUE(S.q)
    ENQUEUE(r, v)

  S.q := r


POP (S):
  RETURN DEQUEUE(S.q)
```

EDIT: Alternative solution that doesn't require temporary queue r:

```
STACK:
  QUEUE q


PUSH (S, x):
  ENQUEUE(S.q, x)

  n := SIZE(S.q) - 1

  repeat n times:
    v := DEQUEUE(S.q)
    ENQUEUE(S.q, v)


POP (S):
  RETURN DEQUEUE(S.q)
```

Comment: Well.. It's O(n). But I can't imagine anything better! Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ implementation of a stack with O(1) push and pop functions.

The interface is similar to std::stack:

```
void push(const T& val);
void pop();
const T& top() const;
bool empty() const;
```

Here is the full code. I couldn't think of a way of avoiding the messy type-casts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <stdexcept>


#define ASSERT(x) \
  if (!(x)) { \
    std::cout << "Assertion failed at line " << __LINE__ << "\n"; \
  } \


template <typename T>
class Stack {
  public:
    Stack()
      : m_head(NULL), m_tail(NULL) {}

    void push(const T& val) {
      std::queue<void*>* tail = new std::queue<void*>();
      tail->push(reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_head));
      tail->push(reinterpret_cast<void*>(m_tail));

      m_head = new std::queue<T>();
      m_head->push(val);

      m_tail = tail;
    }

    void pop() {
      if (m_head) {
        delete m_head;

        m_head = reinterpret_cast<std::queue<T>*>(m_tail->front());
        m_tail->pop();

        std::queue<void*>* tail = reinterpret_cast<std::queue<void*>*>(m_tail->front());
        delete m_tail;
        m_tail = tail;
      }
    }

    const T& top() const {
      if (!m_head) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error retrieving top element; stack empty");
      }

      return m_head->front();
    }

    bool empty() {
      return !m_head;
    }

  private:
    std::queue<T>* m_head;
    std::queue<void*>* m_tail;
};


int main() {
  Stack<int> s;

  s.pop();

  s.push(0);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 0);

  s.push(1);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 1);

  s.push(2);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 2);

  s.push(3);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 3);

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 2)

  s.push(4);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 4);

  s.push(5);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 5);

  s.push(6);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 6);

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 5)

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 4)

  s.push(7);
  ASSERT(s.top() == 7);

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 4)

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 2)

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 1)

  s.pop();
  ASSERT(s.top() == 0)

  s.pop();

  ASSERT(s.empty())

  s.pop();

  int error = false;
  try {
    int x = s.top();
  }
  catch (std::exception&) {
    error = true;
  }

  ASSERT(error == true);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: Interesting to see it implemented in C++. Dynamic typing certainly makes things like this easier to implement.